# Pull full dynamodb table with document model

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

```
string tableName = _awsSettings.TableSettings.Table + _awsSettings.TableSettings.Suffix;
Table table = Table.LoadTable(_amazonDynamoDb, tableName);

DocumentBatchGet batch = table.CreateBatchGet();
await batch.ExecuteAsync();
List<Document> results = batch.Results;
return results.As<Lab>();
```

The above code returns 0 results.  I am hoping to return the entire table.

How can I, using the document model (`Table.LoadTable`), pull the entire table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Table.LoadTable()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/MDynamoDBv2DocumentModelTableLoadTableIDynamoDBStringDynamoDBEntryConversionNET45.html) method returns a [`Table`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItemsDocumentClasses.html) object, which is basically a wrapper for the DynamoDB client. This object does not contain any of the data that is in the actual table in AWS.

To read all of the items in a table, you need to use the [`Table.Scan()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanMidLevelDotNet.html) method. Here is some sample code that uses `scan` to dump the contents of a table to the standard output.

```
    private static void DumpTable(Table table)
    {
        ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter();

        Search search = productCatalogTable.Scan(scanFilter);

        List<Document> documentList = new List<Document>();
        do
        {
            documentList = search.GetNextSet();
            foreach (var document in documentList)
                PrintDocument(document);
        } while (!search.IsDone);
    }

    private static void PrintDocument(Document document)
    {
        //   count++;
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (var attribute in document.GetAttributeNames())
        {
            string stringValue = null;
            var value = document[attribute];
            if (value is Primitive)
                stringValue = value.AsPrimitive().Value.ToString();
            else if (value is PrimitiveList)
                stringValue = string.Join(",", (from primitive
                                in value.AsPrimitiveList().Entries
                                                select primitive.Value).ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", attribute, stringValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, I've headed down this direction.  The problem i'm running into is serializing the scan values to my objects.  There is no nice way to do a JSON.Convert on the data that comes back from scan.

Comment: You can convert a `Document` to Json using the `ToJson` method. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/dynamodb-json-support/

Comment: I misunderstood your code initially.  This is EXACTLY what I wanted.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This C# code is to pull records from a dynamodb table having different guid's using BatchGet or CreateBatchGet

```
        string tablename = "AnyTableName"; //table whose data you want to fetch

        var BatchRead = ABCContext.Context.CreateBatchGet<ABCTable>(  

            new DynamoDBOperationConfig
            {
                OverrideTableName = tablename; 
            });

        foreach(string Id in IdList) // in case you are taking string from input
        {
            Guid objGuid = Guid.Parse(Id); //parsing string to guid
            BatchRead.AddKey(objGuid);
        }

        await BatchRead.ExecuteAsync();
        var result = BatchRead.Results;
```

// ABCTable is the table modal which is used to create in dynamodb & data you want to fetch

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Although your answer contains decent code, I don't thing you've noticed that the questioner requires a document model result.